# Counting roots using contour integral and derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, contour-integration, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be an analytic function on $\overline{B(z,R)}$ with only simple zeroes.
Assume that f has no zeroes on the boundary of the ball.
Let $\gamma=z_{0}+Re^{it}$ be the boundary path.

I want to show that $\intop_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ counts the number of zeroes of $f$ in $B(z_{0},R)$.

I don't know how to attack this problem.

What I am thinking is something along the lines of singularities since
when $z$ is a root then $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is undefined? Also, I am thinking the winding number has to come in play here, since it's the only thing that "counts"...

The only theorem I know that bring these two together is the following:
If $f$ is analytic on $U$, except for poles $z_{1},...,z_{n}$ and $\gamma$ is homologous to 0 on $U$ then

$\intop_{\gamma}f(w)dw=2\pi i{\sum}W(\gamma;z_{i})Res(f,z_{i})$

But it doesn't seem to fit since nothing tells me $f$ has poles and nothing tells me that $\gamma$ is homologous to 0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(z)=0$ then $f'(z) \neq 0$ because zeros are of order 1. Thus $\frac {f'} f$ has a pole of order 1 at each zero of $f$ and no other poles. Just apply Residue Theorem to complete the proof.
If $f(c)=0$ then the residue of $\frac {f'} f$ at $c$ is $\lim _{z \to c} \frac {(z-c)f'(z)} {f{(z)}}=\lim _{z \to c} \frac {(z-c)f'(z)} {f{(z)}-f(c)}=\frac {f'(c)} {f"(c)}=1$ by the definition of $f'(c)$.

Comment: I see. But in order to apply the Residue Theorem don't I need to have $\gamma$ homologous to 0?

Comment: Could you also clarify why If $f(z)=0$ then $f′(z)≠0$ ?

Comment: If $f(z)=f'(z)=0$ then the power series expansion of $f$ around $z$ starts with a second degree term and so the zero is not a simple one: its degree is at least 2, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: @jkbestami any two paths in $B(z,R+\epsilon )$ are homotopoic to each other. specifically $H(t,s)=s \gamma (t)$ shows that $\gamma $ is homologous to 0.

Comment: okay, everything is much clearer. However, I have one last question: once I apply the Residue Theorem, i will get $∫γf(w)dw=2πi∑W(γ;zi)Res(f,zi)$ , How do do I get the residues equal to 1 ? I tried writing a "general" power series for $f(x)$ and one for $f'(x)$ and reasoning about the resulting fraction but I am not getting anywhere...

Comment: @jkbestami I have included the calculation of residue in the answer now.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One thing, I think you mean $\frac{f′(c)}{f'(c)}$ at the end

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.